# Do parasitic infections increase pregnancy rates?

Tags: obstetrics, infectious-diseases, parasites, ringworm

A new [study](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/350/6263/970) suggests that certain intestinal worms increase the number of babies born to women which is mentioned [here](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-34857022) and [here](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/24/science/parasites-found-to-influence-fertility-in-women.html?_r=0). Are parasitic worm infections associated with a statistically significant increase or decrease in fertility in humans?

Comment: What do you mean with "major role"? Globally? Or for the individual?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The study abstract makes it quite clear that it is a novel finding that there is a connection at all. The study is a few days old. If anybody in the world has more knowledge than there is in this study, it is not published yet. So, how do you expect anybody to tell you more than there is in the source you already found yourself? The question you are asking, "significant increase in fertility in humans" is so overly broad, it will take decades of such studies before anyone in the world can give an estimation.

Comment: @rumtscho has a good point, which is a shame because this is a fascinating finding that probably has implications in several arenas, not the least of which is whether the changes the worms induce might confer some sort of reproductive advantage for the worms. Sadly, I probably won't live long enough to find out unless an animal model can be found.

Comment: @Rumtscho-Your comment would be more apt if it is converted to an answe r!